# PHP - INSERT a variable of type Time into a column in MySQL of type Time

Tags: php, mysql, time, insert

I keep getting this error:

"Catchable fatal error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string"

From this code:

```
<?php
   $value_startTime = new DateTime();
   $value_startTime->setTime($value_HourStart,$_POST['TextBoxStartMin'],0);

   $value_endTime = new DateTime();
   $value_endTime->setTime($value_HourEnd,$_POST['TextBoxEndMin'],0);

   $query_InsertJob="INSERT INTO job (jobDesc,timeStart,timeEnd)
   VALUE ('$_POST[TextAreaProblem]','$value_startTime','$value_endTime')";
?>
```

These variables can have values from 00 to 23:
$value_HourStart
$value_HourEnd

These variables can have values from 00 to 59:
$_POST['TextBoxStartMin']
$_POST['TextBoxEndMin']

I am having no trouble with:
$_POST[TextAreaProblem]

What is it that I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert those `DateTime` objects into strings for use in the query.

Try something like this (PDO example because I can't abide encouraging people to use the `mysql_*` functions)

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO job (jobDesc, timeState, timeEnd) VALUES (?, ?, ?)');
$stmt->execute(array(
    $_POST['TextAreaProblem'],
    $value_startTime->format('H:i:s'),
    $value_endTime->format('H:i:s')
));
```

Answer (score 0):

$value_startTime and $value_endTime are objects. Try it with $value_startTime->getTimestamp().

```
$query_InsertJob="INSERT INTO job (jobDesc,timeStart,timeEnd) VALUE ('$_POST[TextAreaProblem]','".$value_startTime->getTimestamp()."','"$value_endTime->getTimestamp()."')";
```